# How to make radio button checked/active depending on current state value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button, state

so I've got a header that cycles through 4 images every 5 seconds. The user can also cycle through these images themselves using 5 radio buttons.

The styling for the active/checked radio button is applied when the user clicks it themselves, however, if the timer switches the image the active radio button remains unchanged.

I know this is the expected behaviour based on my code below, I'm just wondering how I would go about changing the checked radio button to match it's current image!

Any help would be appreciated!

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
      time: 0,
      start: 0,
      currentIndex: 0
  };
  this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);
  this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
  this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.startTimer();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.time === 5) {
        this.setIndex(this.state.currentIndex + 1);
    }
}
startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
        () =>
            this.setState({
                time: this.state.time + 1
            }),
        1000
    );
}
resetTimer() {
    this.setState({ time: 0 });
}

setIndex(index, e) {
    console.log("changing");
    if (index < 0) {
        index = headers.length - 1;
    }
    if (index >= headers.length) {
        index = 0;
    }

    this.setState({
        currentIndex: index,
        time: Date.now() - this.state.start
    });
    this.resetTimer();
}
```

... *skipped code*

```
<div className="carousel">
    <img
       alt="carousel-header"
       className="background-img"
       src={headers[this.state.currentIndex].image}
    />
       <div className="buttons-container">
            <input
                  type="radio"
                   value="1"
                   defaultChecked
                   name="index"
                   onClick={() => this.setIndex(0)}
            ></input>
            <input
                   type="radio"
                   value="2"
                   name="index"
                   onClick={() => this.setIndex(1)}
            ></input>
            <input
                   type="radio"
                   value="3"
                   name="index"
                   onClick={() => this.setIndex(2)}
             ></input>
              <input
                   type="radio"
                   value="4"
                   name="index"
                   onClick={() => this.setIndex(3)}
              ></input>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `currentIndex` for automatic change radio buttons.

In `render` function

```
const { currentIndex } = this.state
```

```
      <div className="buttons-container">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="1"
          defaultChecked
          name="index"
          checked={currentIndex === 0}
          onClick={() => this.setIndex(0)}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="2"
          name="index"
          checked={currentIndex === 1}
          onClick={() => this.setIndex(1)}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="3"
          name="index"
          checked={currentIndex === 2}
          onClick={() => this.setIndex(2)}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="4"
          name="index"
          checked={currentIndex === 3}
          onClick={() => this.setIndex(3)}
        ></input>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are using radio buttons which are getting activated onclick (which is default HTML  behavior) and are not when using your timer.

It is piece of cake, you just need to activate them via JS each time the timer switches background.

You probably assumed that your setIndex() function will run everytime your timer makes a change, but that is not a case, since that function only launches when person physically clicks on radio, or onClick event is emitted.
Because of:

```
onClick={() => this.setIndex(3)}
```

To fix it you should modify this piece of code:

```
startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
        () =>
            this.setState({
                time: this.state.time + 1
            }),
        1000
    );
}
resetTimer() {
    this.setState({ time: 0 });
}
```

There you should set the value of radio box, and update the state of index.

When resetting remember to reset the state value function and set value of radio box to #1 radio.